# Separate parts of the GUI with lines in Glade 3

Tags: c, gtk, glade

Is there an option that I can use to separate parts of my GUI with lines in Glade 3? I want some widgets to be separated from the others; for example I would like to put them in a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GtkSeparator; its icon is the vertical line in the Control and Display section of the tool palette.